# Page zoomed in and not at full viewport width in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am having trouble with a responsive design. Since it is mobile optimized, I included a viewport meta tag which should ensure that the page is load without any zoom and occupies the full viewport. However, here is what happens:

[(Screenshot) When loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogZcs.png)

[(Screenshot) When zooming out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnTKk.png)

For reference, the lower toolbar menu is position:fixed and thus not included in the normal page flow, causing it to be the "normal" width.
This happens in Chrome and Firefox mobile, so I assume it is not browser dependent. A Chrome Remote Device Debugging session revealed that the header is exactly as wide as the <body> and the <html> elements, so the problem is with the page itself and not with the header alone.

Here is my code (menu removed for simplicity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>TremeClothing</h1>
      <form id="search" action="page.php?stuff=things">
        <input type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  font-size: 20pt;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(0, 51, 51);
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

#header h1 {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(102, 153, 153);
  font-size: 3rem;
}

#search {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 16rem;
  margin: 1rem 3rem 0 3rem;
}

#search input {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(102, 153, 153) no-repeat 0.5rem 0.5rem/2rem url(img/icons/search.svg);
  color: rgb(0, 51, 51);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

#search input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your page is zooming correctly.**

The reason the search bar is starting to slide off the page is because your `#search` has a fixed width, `16rem`, which, adding to a fixed margin of `3rem` on either side, comes out to slightly wider than your phone screen. Try using this for your `#search` styles:

```
display: inline-block;
height: 3rem;
width: 80%;
max-width: 16rem;
margin: 1rem 10% 0 10%;
```

This will ensure that the width of your `#search` is fluid, and never more than 100% of the width of the screen.